# Can a plugin's impersonation setting be disregarded?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a plugin registered against `Account` entity, `Assign` message, `Post-Operation (stage 40)` which has to perform some magic on related records.

I registered the step specifying `ADMINISTRATOR` under `Run in User's Context` because the magic requires more permissions than users commonly have: impersonating the admin seems the correct way to act.

If I proceed to try out the plugin using a "normal" user (let's call it `TESTUSER`), I see that impersonation doesn't seem to "stick".

Assuming the users look like this:

```
ADMINISTRATOR - guid AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA
TESTUSER      - guid FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF
```

This is what I see upon debugging the plugin execution:

```
PluginExecutionContext.UserId           -> FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF
PluginExecutionContext.InitiatingUserId -> FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF
```

And the plugin in turn complains that user with guid FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF is missing some privileges (which is true, that's exactly why I set the step to be run in a different user's context, who has those privileges and should be in charge of the operations performed)

I assumed that if I set `Run in user context` to something else than `Calling User` then the plugin would impersonate another user, am I wrong about it ?

I didn't include any source code because I don't believe it's relevant (the plugin is working, up until the point where it blows up because of missing privileges, because of being running under the wrong user...)

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to specifying user in plugin registration tool, you can create new instance of service like in line below, and use it to execute actions that need full privileges:

```
IOrganizationService adminservice = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(null);
```

All calls to adminservice methods will be executed as SystemUser with administrator permissions.